# Why do I get stuck at "running pre-commit checks... running style:" on git commit

Tags: git

Suddenly since this evening every time I run git commit, it gets stuck at this "running style" message. Interesting bit is that even if I dont even have anything to commit in my repo, I still get stuck there.

```
$ git st
On branch test-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git commit
running pre-commit checks...
running style:
```

I upgraded my git to latest version 2.2.2 using homebrew, but problem still exists. I cloned the repo in different directory, and git is working fine there, so am sure the problem is in my local repo. Any idea how to fix this?

If I have to I can delete this clone and re-clone it from remote, but I have lots of local branches not pushed to remote yet, how would I bring those over to new clone?

Comment: The message "running pre-commits checks" implies you're using a pre-commit hook, and it's printing that and running some stuff.  Presumably it runs something that never finishes.  What do you have in your pre-commit hook?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a git problem, but a problem with the project.  The project has added a [pre-commit hook](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), a program which runs when you try to commit something.  It should be in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.  You'll have to fix it, or report it as a bug to the project.

You could simply delete it, but it might do something important for the project.